# convert to mysql prepared statement

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I am trying to study how prepared statement works in MySQL, I was told that all the codes I am using are vulnerable to MySQL injection, I am using codeigniter php models to write this mysql query code like this for example.

```
public function getOpenLoans($id){
            $query = 'select a.Amount as OpenLoanAmount , a.monthly_amortization as totalInstallment
                      from useropenloan a 
                      where a.Owner = ' .$id. ' and UPDATE_DT is null' ; 

            $query = $this->db->query($query);
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
        }
```

Which basically gets a row with some information, but what I really want to know is how to 
convert it to prepared mysql statement, I tried following different methods in stackoverflow and some youtube tutorials but they do not work, so could someone help me write this code in prepared sql statement.

I tried it in this way

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare(select a.Amount as OpenLoanAmount , a.monthly_amortization as totalInstallment
                          from useropenloan a 
                          where a.Owner = :id and UPDATE_DT is null);
$stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: Do you have quotes around the SQL?

Comment: @copynpaste in the second prepare(select ... ) no i am not using any quotes

Comment: Add them, this is just a string

Comment: @copynpaste arrite added, but my main concern is does this help in stopping sql injection?

Comment: you stop SQL-injection by removing your values from the query-string and use parameters instead. but it still has to be a string, otherwise it just doesn't work.

Comment: Yes this should stop SQL injection

Comment: @FranzGleichmann I am using bindParam, wont that help?

Comment: how is this remotely connected to codeigniter? Can we remove that tag?

Comment: @Drew using codeigniter models, so added it there, I can remove it.

Comment: @copynpaste I used it, but after execute, how can I return the string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function getOpenLoans($id){
  $sql = "select a.Amount as OpenLoanAmount , a.monthly_amortization as totalInstallment from useropenloan a where a.Owner = ? and UPDATE_DT is null";
  $query = $this->db->query($sql, array($id));
  $result - $query->result();
  return $result;
}
```

Comment: Koning, I am using codeigniter, so it for some reasons stops at $conn, so should i be using $this->db->prepare ?

Comment: I used the assumption that $conn is an existing PDO connection. See http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php for details on how to setup one.

Comment: This is how I execute the old query
$query = $this->db->query($query);
            $result = $query->result();
            return $result;
, so it must be in a diff way right ?

Comment: codeigniter already provides a way to connect to the database, by this $this->db->  so on... but i tried using it, doesnt work

Comment: Sorry I missed the part about the CodeIgniter.  I have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: Thanks alot for the answer, will check it out now, but wanted to ask, if I had more variables, are all like ? ? , and then in the array it would be ($id, $name) so on ?

Comment: Yes as long as the order is the same.

Comment: Thanks alot for the help, one last question, is this now less vulnerable to mysql injection right ?

Comment: I would assume so. You can have a look at the CI implementation at https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/develop/system/database/DB_driver.php It seems like it calls a compile_binds() function that does a regex validation on the array's input variables. Also see https://arjunphp.com/prevent-sql-injection-codeigniter/